# Is the Camera class supported across all Android Devices?

Tags: android

I am working on an app and using the Camera class that comes with the Android SDK. The class seems to work on my Galaxy Ace, but I've read that it doesn't work on all Android devices. Here's the function I call:

```
Camera camera;
camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawPictureCallback, jpegPictureCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes OEM's customize default behavior and takePicture was introduced in API level 5. I'm also using this in one of my application and till now I haven't seen a device not supporting this.
Can you be more specific on which device it's not working?

Comment: Maybe I am not into the right stuff. I read something [here](http://handycodeworks.com/?p=19). Not sure if it's an issue just with the preview or the takePicture method. Please see if you can clarify.

Comment: You need to start preview before calling takepicture and once you have successfully saved the bitmap you get in onPictureTaken (in PictureCallback) you need to refresh the preview.
Also refresh the preview in onResume call.

Comment: Sorry, but how do you refresh the preview?

Comment: You need to set the previewHolder again to your camera and also do any parameter initialization if needed to the camera.

Comment: Okay. The camera doesn't seem to be taking very clear pictures, in some cases it's just a black image. Do you happen to know how to handle that?

Comment: You need to select the best preview size for the device. If you have hardcoded the best preview size then it will show black screen for devices on which that preview size is not supported.